# Twig doesn't extend template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

My problem is next:
I have `base.html.twig` placed in `view` folder (root)

```
    {# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}Test Application{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
    {% block sidebar %}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    {% endblock %}
</div>
<div id="content">
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and `index.html.twig` in `Blog` directory (views/Blog):

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
{{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}

    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    {% for entry in blog_entries %}
        <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is next:
When I render and return that template it is shown just as `index.html.twig` and it doesn't use any part from the base template. Even I `{{ parent() }}` doesn't work (is not showing anything). Please help!

EDIT: it shows just articles part

Answer (score 4):

Hah... I made it work... Simply changed `::base.html.twig` with `AcmeHelloBundle::base.html.twig` ;)

Comment: you said this : `placed in view folder (root)`. this : `AcmeHelloBundle::base.html.twig` is not in the root folder, we couldn't help you. congrats you solved it yourself

Comment: In the comments of the `::base.html.twig` the root path was given wrong aswell.